# Execute code after all payment methods are rendered on checkout

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

I need to execute a code once all the payment methods are loaded (rendered) on the checkout (using the onepage solution).

I can't find the way to achieve that.

My final goal is  to create a custom "Place Order" button underneath all payment methods that would be enabled only if a payment method is selected (even after a refresh page when the selected option is stored in the local storage).

Comment: Are you familiar with `events/observer` ?

Comment: @PartabSaifuddinZakir haven't used them yet but understand the concept. Do you know which event is triggered when le payment methods are rendered/loaded? Also, I guess this solution works with PHP, is there a way to retrieve this information with JS?

Comment: @Dim13i have you found any solution using which we can execute code after payment methods rendered?

Comment: Bump!! I would love to know the an answer to this.